# binary relations defining an equivalence relation on S

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations, binary, binary-operations

Is this a true statement for binary relations defines an equivalence relation
on S:

S is the set of all n-digit binary sequences. We say that two binary sequences
are in a relation if and only if they have the same number of 1s.

Comment: As equality is an equivalence, this seems pretty obvious, don't you think?

Comment: Is there a proof or a theorem or something to go with this?

Comment: You just have to say that, if $s$ and $t$ are $n$-digit binary sequences, if $x$ has the same number of $1$s as $t$, the $t$ has the same number of $1$s as $s$, for instance. It's *really* obvious, unless I didn't understand well what's your relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f:S\to X$ is some function then the relation $\sim$ on $S$ prescribed by: $$s\sim s'\iff f(s)=f(s')$$ is an equivalence relation. This simply because for all $s,t,r\in S$:

- $f(s)=f(s)$ (reflexivity)
- $f(s)=f(t)\implies f(t)=f(s)$ (symmetry)
- $f(s)=f(t)\wedge f(t)=f(r)\implies f(s)=f(r)$ (transitivity)

In your question let $f$ be the function that sends each sequence to its number of $1$'s.

Comment: I see thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.